# SharePoint 2010 REST Date/Time format

Tags: 2010, rest, date-time, date-format

In SharePoint 2010 REST API when I call to `_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents(38)/Created` and get JSON response the date/time is returned as `/Date(1421146908000)/` (I found [some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818719/how-to-handle-json-datetime-returned-from-wcf-data-services-odata) about it but not still sure what this number counts and from which epoch).
But when I get actual value calling to `_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents(38)/Created/$value`, I get `Edm.DateTime` value `2015-01-13T11:01:48`.

Does anyone know

1. Is it always the case I can rely on? The reason is that I use actually `_vti_bin/ListData.svc/` service of SP 2013 server (since I don't have SP 2010).
2. Is there some official information about date/time formats returned in different cases?
3. Is it really `Edm.DateTime` or may be `Edm.DateTimeOffset`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [protocol specification document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541461.aspx) `Edm.DateTime` (`VJsonDateTime`) has the following JSON format:

```
VJsonDateTime= quotation-mark  
              "\/Date(" 
              ticks
              [("+" / "-") offset]
              ")\/" 
              quotation-mark 

ticks       = *DIGIT 

; ticks is the number of milliseconds since midnight  
; January 1, 1970 

offset      = 4DIGIT
; offset represents the number of minutes to add (if preceded by "+") or substract
(if preceded by "-") from the time value represented by ticks
; if no offset is specified, the value MUST be interpreted as UTC.

;Note: This format is the same used by the ASP.NET 
;AJAX framework, described in http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-;us/library/bb299886.aspx
```

From another hand, the document states that *DateTimeOffset in JSON should follow the same format as the Date in JSON* :

```
VJsonDateTimeOffset =  VJsonDateTime
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadim - you helps as it always. Do you know is it always the case that getting the value (via `$value`) instead of JSON returns `Edm.DateTime`? I noticed that SP 2013 returns `Edm.DateTimeOffset` format

Comment: Andrii, that's a nice question, will try to find out and get back to you

Comment: Another note is that JSON returns milliseconds while string `$value` returns no fractional part of `OData.DateTimeOffset`, so JSON precision is **millisecond** but direct `$value` is **limited to second** (despite that `OData.DateTimeOffset` supports any precision).